# Symmetric black-hole curves

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Is there a curve $C$ that connects $(0,1)$ to $(a,0)$ for some $a>0$, and, when reflected
to $C'$ in the $x$-axis, the shape $S=C \cup C'$ has the property that each horizontal
light ray entering $S$ from the left reflects off of $S$ (interpreted as a perfect mirror)
in such a way that it never emerges, i.e. it never again crosses $x=0$?

For example, a straight line $C$ fails to be such a curve:

     [image: BlackHoleNot]

Comment: I think that would violated Liouville's theorem (this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29).

Comment: @Joseph: Are you looking for a curve which causes an incoming light ray to reflect infinitely many times on it without crossing the line $x=0$? Or are you instead looking for a curve which causes the light to stay trapped inside indefinitely in time? The latter condition may be harder to specify rigorously when the set of instants at which reflections happen has limit points.

Comment: The latter condition is just infinite trajectory length...

Comment: @fedja: I guess all that I meant is that it might be hard to define reflection at an instant in time which is a limit point of reflection instants.

Comment: OK, add "with finitely many reflections on any finite length piece of trajectory" then :). I guess I may have an idea how to capture the rays coming in across $(0.5,1)$ but the whole interval $(0,1)$ is harder. Or, perhaps, I'm talking nonsense. I need some more time to figure out if I have anything interesting to tell :).

Comment: Geometric optics is a particular limit of a wave equation. Certainly time reversibility of that equation and thermodynamics should tell you that the steady state solution where a constant stream of parallel rays approaches from the left must result in an equal amount of power leaving (or else we can time-reverse the solution and have a free power source). Same goes for any finite fraction of rays being captured.

Comment: I was looking for trapping the lightrays (and thus the title "black hole"), regardless of how it is achieved. Perhaps pieces of parabolas and ellipses stitched together ...

Comment: Are you happy with piecewise smooth solution? If YES:
An example of black hole for a strip of horizontal light rays can be constructed from two arcs of parabolas with common focus and vertical directrixes.
Then you can add horizontal mirrors and take a pair of them with reflections in $x$-axis and get the curve you want.

Comment: At Anton: That's pretty much what I thought too but the devil is in the details and I have no time now. At Yoav: Not quite. You know, the standard "explosion at infinity" solution of the heat equation would be quite a mighty power source too and here the infinity is just brought to a finite point. Needless to say, the curve should have a complicated structure at every scale near $(a,0)$, so no physical considerations can really apply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will do it since Fedya has no time.

An example of black hole for a strip of horizontal light rays can be constructed from two arcs of parabolas with common focus and vertical directrixes.
[image: black hole with a gap]

You can add horizontal mirrors and take a pair of them with reflections in $x$-axis and get the curve you want, say as it shown on the following picture.

[image: black hole without gap]

Comment: Cool! I perceived the question as asking about a graph of a smooth function tending to $0$ at $a$ (in which case you should be much more careful and create some structure of focusing and "parallelizing" chambers whose sizes go to $0$ but not too fast as you approach $a$), but, most likely, your example cannot be surpassed in clarity :).

Comment: Very cool. This is very similar to the ellipsoid paradox (see http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.3596430 ), but with one focus taken to infinity. I see now how the physical objections are circumvented. Specifically, with Liouville's theorem, a "packet" of particles gets horizontally spread out as it gets vertically squished and eventually the front of the packet overlaps the back of it so the "phase space" volume taken up by the packet is no longer conserved.

Comment: The volume was 0 to start with: all rays are initially going in one direction ;).

Comment: Yes, :). Still, in this case the rays keep coming back to the space of horizontal rays, so in the measure restricted to that space what I said still makes sense (I think).

Comment: Actually, scratch that. What I said doesn't make any sense at all. The phase space area can't overlap itself because of reversibility. Liouville's theorem just doesn't apply here for the reason you said, which is the volume is zero to start with.

Comment: Beautiful! I think perhaps you truncated the curve a bit prematurely at the top & bottom? I think rays will hit those horizontal truncations...?

Comment: They will but then you just trace their mirror images until they come back to the "physical domain". Or, indeed, just wait until the parabolae intersect by themselves.

Comment: P.S. One may use such construction to come to close to a system of radars with single transmitter without being detected. Maybe it is already used(?)